# 一つのプログラムで複数の連結リストの作成

Tags: c, アルゴリズム, array, データ構造

配列を使わず、連結リスト（単方向）のみでキューのデータ構造を実装したいです。 C言語を用いて、一つのプログラムで複数の連結リストを実装することは可能でしょうか？structの定義で行き詰まってしまったので、実例も教えてくださると嬉しいです…。
追記

```
struct node1
{   
    int data1;
    struct node1 *next1;
};

struct node2
{   
    int data2;
    struct node2 *next2;
};
```

連結リストで2つのキューを実装し、2行の結果を出力したいです。上記したstructを2つ作る方法だと、enqueue, dequeueなどの関数を作る際にそのリスト専用の関数を作らなければいけないのか？と思ってそこから手が止まってしまいました。

最終的なゴールは、配列を用いず入力Nを読み込み、評価して2つの連結リストにそれぞれ結果をストアし、その結果を順に出力することです。 配列では実装できたのですが、時間がかかりすぎてしまいます。

追記2
要素数は最大1000000です。タイムリミットが1sのため、配列を用いたプログラムではTLEを返されてしまうので、それ以外の代替方法として連結リストを使えないかと思って質問させていただきました。

追記3
入力の条件は、

> The first line contains the integer N. The second line contains N integers, a0,a1,...,aN−1. The integers are separated by a single space character. The third line contains N integers, b0,b1,...,bN−1. The integers are separated by a single space character.

となっています。
現時点では、

```c
scanf("%d", &N) //入力される要素数
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    scanf("%d",&b[i]); //aiの範囲を指定する数bi

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=1;j<b[i];j++){
        if(//評価){
              L[i] = (i-j) //配列に代入
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=1;j<b[i];j++){
        if(//評価){
              R[i] = (i-j) //配列に代入
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    printf()//L,Rの要素をすべて出力
```

というようなコードを書きました。これ以外の方法が思いつかなくて詰まっている状態です。スタックを使う方法も考えたのですが…

Comment: `C 単方向 連結リスト キュー`等のキーワードで検索すると、該当のWikipediaとか色々出てきます。[連結リスト - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E7%B5%90%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88), [ポインタを使ったデータ構造](https://wwws.kobe-c.ac.jp/deguchi/c/list/frame.html), [アルゴリズムとデータ構造](http://www-ikn.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/~arim/pub/algo/algo3.pdf), [連結リスト①（単方向・線形）](https://programming-place.net/ppp/contents/algorithm/data_struct/003.html) 複数作るというのは、これらの基点となる変数を複数用意すれば良いだけですが、この辺の記事を良く見て、やりたいことの詳細を掘り下げてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 「配列では実装できたのですが、時間がかかりすぎてしまいます」とありますが、要素数はどのくらいあるのでしょうか? 単純な単方向リストの場合、キューの操作は配列より時間がかかるのが普通ですが。

Comment: それは[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)なのでは？ まず「配列では時間がかかりすぎる」処理の何が問題か/改善点は無いか、を探った方が良い気がします。

Comment: 「タイムリミットが1sのため、配列を用いたプログラムではTLEを返されてしまう」と言うことなら、配列を使ったキューの実装が不適切であるのだと思われます。キュー操作のたびに配列の中身を移動させるような実装になっているのではないですか? 現在のご質問内容もそれなりに意味のあるものなので、こちらは(承認した上で)残しておいて、別途配列を用いた効率的なキューの実装方法について、あらたにご質問を書かれた方が良いように思います。なお、「TLEを返されてしまう」とあるので、何かの競技プログラミングを解かれているのでしょうか? だとしたら、その課題の他の縛りやあなたの「TLEを返されてしまう」コードなども参考のために含められるとより回答しやすくなります。

Comment: コードのご提示ありがとうございます。最大1000000回繰り返されるforループの中にさらにネストしてforループが存在するので、これではとても1sどころの実行時間では終わらないだろうことは予想がつきますが、これはリストを使っても同じことで、1000000回繰り返されるループの内側でまたループしていればやはり1s制限を満たすことはできないでしょう。このような出題では問題に固有の条件を加味してアルゴリズムを工夫(二重ループなんかが現れないように)しないと、制限事項を満たせないように設定されています。「enqueue, dequeueなどの関数を作る際にそのリスト専用の関数を作らなければいけないのか？」と言うこの質問の当初の疑問は解決されたはずですので、解決に必要な情報(全文引用に問題があれば、リンク先を示すなどでも結構です)を記載した新しいご質問として再度質問してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

連結リストがふたつ欲しいだけであれば、同じ struct の型を持った変数をふたつ定義すれば良いです。struct をふたつ定義する必要はありません。

```c
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node;

...

int main()
{
    /* ... */
    node * list1 = /* ...初期化処理... */;
    node * list2 = /* ...初期化処理... */;
    /* ... */
}
```